# Serverless correctly format dict-parameter in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, serverless

I am trying to invoke a serverless task in Windows where I have a Python dict as one parameter of the general form

```
sls invoke -f server -s dev --aws-profile user-admin -d '{"type":"python","path":"callbacks.reload"}'
```

From the associated Python code, I get the error `'str' object has no attribute 'get'` as apparently, `'{"type":"python","path":"callbacks.reload"}'` is handled as a string instead of a dict. The same code works for a colleague on a Mac, so I assume it has to do with my System:

- Windows 10
- Anaconda 2.3.2
- Python 3.9.16
- Serverless Framework Core 3.24.1
- Serverless Plugin 6.2.2
- Serverless SDK 4.3.2
- Powershell in Visual Studio Code 1.81.1

I assume the problem is with the incorrect handling of the `-d '{"type":"python","path":"callbacks.reload"}'` parameter being treated as a string instead of a dictionary. I tried different versions of inner and outer quotation marks such as

- `"{'type':'python','path':'callbacks.reload'}"`
- `"{\"type\":\"python\",\"path\":\"callbacks.reload\"}"`
- `"{"type":"python","path":"callbacks.reload"}"`
- `'{'type':'python','path':'callbacks.reload'}'`

but none worked.